# SSRS expression replace NULL with another field value

Tags: reporting-services

I need to write an SSRS expression  to check and replace NULL field value with another field value. Can this be done?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
=iif(isNothing(Fields!FV1.Value), Fields!FV2.Value, Fields!FV1.Value)
```

Comment: Yes - the above was very helpful.  Many Thanks L

Answer (score 40):

If you have to do it a bunch of times, you can also make a [reusable function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-code-to-a-report-ssrs) to avoid a lot of typing.  Here's a solution modeled off of [SQL's ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function:

1. Right click on the Report Document and go to Report Properties.

   [image: Report Properties]
2. Navigate to the Code tab and add the following function:

   ```vb
   Public Function IsNull(input As Object, defaultValue As Object) As Object
     Return IIf(input Is Nothing, defaultValue, input)
   End Function
   ```

   [image: Report Properties > Code]

   <sup>**Note** - Even though the custom code is expecting valid VB.NET code, you [have to use the `IIF` Ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27418185/1366033).</sup>
3. Then you can use it in an expression like this:

   ```
   =Code.IsNull(Fields!MyField.Value,0)
   ```

   [image: Field Expression]

Comment: Although both answers are correct, I very much like the potential for reuse with this solution. Especially if you have a complex expression where you're aggregating a field. In that instance this is a much more readable and reusable solution.

Comment: 3 years after - but i found this to be very useful.