# How to replace NULL values in SSRS with words?

Tags: reporting-services, null, ssrs-2012

I do not have much experience in SSRS and I've realized that the best way to replace NULL values from a result set (returned to SSRS) is to use this:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!MyField.Value),"NA",Fields!MyFields.Value)
```

But how to apply this exactly? I'm not sure what to do with this line. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234993/ssrs-expression-replace-null-with-another-field-value

Comment: unfortunately that link did not have the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the text box you want the information to appear, click Expression
and enter script in the box.

voila.

[image]

Comment: If you also VOTE UP the question, it will help others because right now with zero votes it doens't show up in searches....

Answer (score 0):

You could use the COALESCE command in your SQL statement.

```
SELECT COALESCE(MyField,'N/A') AS 'MyField' FROM dbo.clients
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this problem had to be resolved at the SSRS level (as access to code isn't avaiable for this instance)