# IIF statement missing something

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm way out of my element with SSRS Expressions.  I'm hoping someone could lend me a hand.

I have 2 name fields:

- `ContactName`
- `BusinessName`

If `ContactName` is NOT NULL then only use the `ContactName`.
However, if `ContactName` is NULL and `BusinessName` is NOT NULL then use the `BusinessName`.

I tried the following:

```
    =IIF(NOT
         Fields!ContactName.Value Is Nothing, 
         Fields!ContactName.Value, 
         Fields!BusinessName.Value
        )
```

However, it isn't picking up when I only have a `BusinessName`.

What do I need to do to also display the `BusinessName` when I only have a `BusinessName`?

**Just as an update:**

The answer was a combination of the IIF statement and a check to see if the value was also an empty string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS expression replace NULL with another field value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234993/ssrs-expression-replace-null-with-another-field-value)

Comment: Switch ContactName and BusinessName and try `=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!ContactName.Value), Fields!BusinessName.Value,Fields!ContactName.Value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSRS, **ISNOTHING** is a function that requires an argument.

Your expression just needs a little change to put your field in the argument:

```
 =IIF(NOT ISNOTHING(Fields!ContactName.Value), 
         Fields!ContactName.Value, 
         Fields!BusinessName.Value
        )
```

Comment: Does ISNOTHING also cover NULLS and blanks?

Comment: ISNOTHING is just for NULLS. You'd have to add another check for empty string ("").  `NOT (ISNOTHING(Fields!ContactName.Value) OR Fields!ContactName.Value = "")`

Comment: It wound up using both statements.  Now it works!  thanks for your help!